# GMM Estimation with HAC Weight Matrix in R

Tags: econometrics, regression, r, gmm

I am currently working on my econometrics assignment regarding a seminal paper of John Taylor (1993) and really got stuck during the last days with one specific question. I am supposed to set up a GMM model with a HAC weight matrix in R and use the lags of different variables as instruments. Furthermore I shall use the difference inflation expectation and inflation target in the model but I have neither information about the inflation expectation nor about the inflation target.

In detail, the model I should estimate looks as follows:

[image]

[image]

I am currently trying to estimate the model with the r function pgmm, but don't even know how the equation is supposed to look like which I will estimate since I have no information about inflation expectation and inflation target.

```
gmm_model_2b =  pgmm(ff ~ lead(inf, 12) + capgap | lag(ff, 1) +
            lag(ff, 2) + lag(inf, 1) + lag(inf, 2) + lag(capgap, 2) + lag(capgap,2),
            data = greenspan_df, effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps")
```

I would be incredibly grateful if anyone could help me with my issue!

Best
J